# React functional component access state in useeffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, react-functional-component

I've gote some react component like below. I can use "messages" in return, but if I try to access messages inside some function, or useEffect, as in example, I always become initial value. How can I solve it in functional component? Thanks

```
const Messages = () => {

   const { websocket } = useContext(WebsocketsContext);

   let [ messages, setMessages ] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
      getMessages()
      .then(result => {
         setMessages(result);
      })
   }, []);

   useEffect(() => {
      if(websocket != null){
         websocket.onmessage = (msg) => {
            let wsData = JSON.parse(msg.data);

            if(wsData.message_type == 'Refresh'){
               console.log(messages)
            };
         };
      };
   }, [websocket]);

   return(
        <div>...</div>    
   );

};
export default Messages;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have encountered a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)

the useEffect with `[websockets]` in its dependency array will only ever "update" whenever the websocket reference/value changes. Whenever it does, the function will have created a "closure" around `messages` at that point in time. Thus, the value of messages will stay as is within that closure. If messages updates after websocket has been created, it will never update the value of "messages" within the onmessage callback function.

To fix this, add "messages" to the dependency array. `[websockets, messages]`. This will ensure the useEffect callback always has the latest state of messages, and this the onmessage function will have the latest state of messages.

```
 useEffect(() => {
      if(websocket != null){
         websocket.onmessage = (msg) => {
            let wsData = JSON.parse(msg.data);

            if(wsData.message_type == 'Refresh'){
               console.log(messages)
            };
         };
      };
   }, [websocket, messages]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was easy )

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `getMessages()` is an async function. The order is as follows: component mounts initially and values are initialized -> componentDidMount() is invoked meaning your `getMessages()` is invoked (an async function!) -> your `webaocket` is initialized and invokes the second `useEffect`, which reads the initial value of `messages` -> your `getMessages` gets its response and sets the `messages` accordingly.

To make it work as intended, make the second `useEffect`'s dependency array as `[websocket, messages]`.